# Recipe for paper glue

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

I need to produce paper bags. Is there any simple receipt for making paper glue so that brown (packaging) paper will stick to itself?

Comment: ...do you have access to polyvinyl alcohol and other chemical ingredients, or you just want to use around-the-house stuff?

Comment: both recipes would be appreciated

Comment: [This](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Glue) looks promising for homemade

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways of making your own glue, here are four different versions you can try :

Simple Glue Ingredients:
1/2 cup flour
1/3 cup water

Paper Mache Glue Ingredients:
1 cup flour
1/3 cup sugar
1-1/2 cup water with 1 tsp white vinegar mixed in

Cornstarch Paste Ingredients:
1-1/2 cups cold water
2 tablespoons cornstarch
2 tablespoons corn syrup
1 teaspoon white vinegar

Simple No-Cook Flour Paste:
1 cup flour
1/2 cup water
1/8 teaspoon salt

Taken from http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Glue